# Using pwelch to a set of signals: some questions (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, spectral-density

I would like to use pwelch on a set of signals and I have some questions.

First, let's say that we have 32 (EEG) signals of 30 seconds duration. The sampling frequency is `fs=256` samples/sec, and thus each signal has length 7680. I would like to use `pwelch` in order to estimate the power spectral density (PSD) of those signals.

**Question 1:**
Based on the `pwelch`'s [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html),

> pxx = pwelch(x) returns the power spectral density (PSD) estimate, pxx, of the input signal, x, found using Welch's overlapped segment averaging estimator. When x is a vector, it is treated as a single channel. When x is a matrix, the PSD is computed independently for each column and stored in the corresponding column of pxx.

However, if call `pwelch` as follows

```
% ch_signals: 7680x32; one channel signal per each column
[pxx,f] = pwelch(ch_signals);
```

the resulting `pxx` is of size `1025x1`, not `1025x32` as I would expect, since the documentation states that if x is a matrix the PSD is computed independently for each column and stored in the corresponding column of pxx.

**Question 2:** 
Let's say that I overcome this problem, and I compute the PSD of each signal independently (by applying `pwelch` to each column of `ch_signals`), I would like to know what is the best way of doing so. Granted that the signal is a 30-second signal in time with sampling frequency `fs=256`, how should I call `pwelch` (with what arguments?) such that the PSD is meaningful?

**Question 3:** If I need to split each of my 32 signals into windows and apply pwech to each one of those windows, what would be the best approach? Let's say that I would like to split each of my 30-second signals into windows of 3 seconds with an overlap of 2 seconds. How should I call `pwelch` for each one of those windows?

Comment: The document is for R2015 beta, probably yours isn't R2015. For example mine is R2012 and it says nothing when `x` is a matrix! The `window` in `pwelch(x,window)` isn't what you mean?

Comment: @Rashid The documentation refers to the latest release which is *R2015b* where **b** stands for the second release of the year. This scheme is being used since 2006.

Comment: @Rashid, correct, I'm on Matlab R2014a and -indeed- it doesn't say anything about this case. Thanks! So, in this case I just iterate over channels, this is totally ok. What my issue really is concerns the questions 2 and 3: how should I apply `pwelch` in these cases (arguments?). Especially in the second case (Q3), where the signal needs to be split in a number of windows beforehand. Here the larger the number of windows, the better. Many thanks for your response!

Comment: In R2014b they introduced multichannel support for `pwelch` and other functions ([Reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/release-notes.html)). *Q2* and *Q3* is not really regarding programming but more about the parametrization. Perhaps ask this in [SPSE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) to get a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for comments @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, just like your case,

The results show that the algorithm indicates the signal frequencies just right.

Each column of matrix, `y` is a sinusoidal to check how it works.

The windows are 3 seconds with 2 seconds of overlapping,

```
Fs = 256;                       
T = 1/Fs;                    
t = (0:30*Fs-1)*T;           
y = sin(2 * pi * repmat(linspace(1,100,32)',1,length(t)).*repmat(t,32,1))';
for i = 1 : 32
[pxx(:,i), freq] = pwelch(y(:,i),3*Fs,2*Fs,[],Fs); %#ok
end
plot(freq,pxx);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); 
ylabel('Spectral Density (Hz^{-1})');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Just one more thing. Your answer concerns my 2nd question. What about the third? What would be a good use of `pwelch` in case I want to split the original signal in windows of 3 seconds with 2 seconds overlap? I mean what should be the call of `pwelch` for each of those windows? In the sense that applying `pwelch` to a 3-second signal may lean to poor results... Could that be the case?

Comment: @nullgeppetto, Why don't you use 3sec windows of Hamming with 2sec overlapping, like in my post?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Let's forget about the 32 signals. Let's say we have just a single signal of 30 seconds with fs=256. Let's assume that I don't want to apply pwelch to the whole signal, but I need to split it first into windows and apply pwelch to each window. Would that be meaningful? We have two kinds of windows here, I know it may be confusing...

Comment: @nullgeppetto, you can use `reshape(y,3*Fs,32,[]);` to split your signal then two `for` loops can solve the problem. But I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @nullgeppetto, it seems you want to see which frequencies happen in each 3sec window. You can consider time-frequency distributions and wavelet maybe.

Comment: @nullgeppetto, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) for short time Fourier transform, check out the graphs (time vs frequency).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @nullgeppetto, you're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer.